# How to set volume name when converting MacOSPath to POSIX

Tags: c++, macos, posix, macos-carbon

In a **Carbon** app I need to convert an HFS style MacOS path into a POSIX one that can be used in an fopen() call. For example:

*my Vol:myFolder:myFile.jpg*

to something like:

*/my Vol/myFolder/myFile.jpg*

If *my Vol* is my sytem disk, */myFolder/myFile.jpg* works just fine, but if it's on a different volume, it does not work (ie. *my Vol/myFolder/myFile.jpg* fails.

How to I specify the volume here?

Thanks!

Bill

Comment: I'm not sure if I edited this right, because the example is inconsistent about whether the path separator is a colon or a slash, so I don't know if it's supposed to be an HFS path.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan:  Yes, and `kCFURLHFSPathStyle` still refers to a colon-delimited path.

Comment: Whiiiich is why my answer used it. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approach that avoids hard-coding (consider a volume not mounted in `/Volumes/`, such as a manually mounted one.)

```
CFStringRef myHFSPath = CFSTR("Macintosh HD:Some Folder:Some Subfolder:Some File");

CFURLRef url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(NULL, myHFSPath, kCFURLHFSPathStyle, FALSE);
if (url) {
    UInt8 posixPath[PATH_MAX * 2]; /* Extra-large because why not? */
    if (CFURLGetFileSystemRepresentation(url, TRUE, posixPath, sizeof(posixPath)) {
        /*
            posixPath now contains a C string suitable for passing to BSD and
            C functions like fopen().
        */
    }
    CFRelease(url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For POSIX style paths you need to preface secondary volumes with "/Volumes". So your example would be, */Volumes/myVol/myFolder/myFile.jpg*. Note even if *myVol* is your system disk this works. So prefacing with */Volumes* is always safe.

Comment: Eeeeh! This is hard-coding and subject to failure in the future or on a non-standard system configuration.